# How to add elements directly to FrameLayout at android:id/content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, glsurfaceview

I've been having some issues with understandng the view hierarchy of my app/device (as I'm having some problems with my application's splashscreen).

Basically, my app is an openGL ES 2.0 game and has the following elements:

- Splashscreen's view (this is a standard Android View)
- Main application's view (this is a GLSurfaceView)
- Resources are loaded in the background (in an AsyncTask)

All I'm doing is this:

**Creating my layout**

```
 layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
 layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

**Addding my GLSurfaceView and Splashscreen**

```
 layout.addView(myGLView);
 layout.addView(splashscreen);  //loads resources on an AsyncTask
```

**Removing the Splashscreen**

When everything is loaded and ready, I simply remove the Splashscreen to reveal the GLSurfaceView underneath:

```
 layout.removeView(splashscreen);
```

When inspecting the view heirarchy of my app I see the following:

### - **My App's views**

[image]

### - **Another Apps' Views**

[image]

As you can see from the above graphics, my app has it's **RelativeLayout** which is the layout I'm creating in code (see above).  This then gets added to the **FrameLayout** which has the resource ID of **android:id/content**.

I've downloaded 3 apps from the Play Store and inspected their layouts and they all have their views listed *directly below* this **FrameLayout**.

My question is what exactly is this **FrameLayout** and how can I get access to it and add my views (Main app, Banner ads, splashscreen), directly to it?

I have had a look around and none of the things I've read have really answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an activity's root view and can be fetched like this:

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Comment: Hi @user3249477 - thanks for this.  I'm unsure how I add elements directly to it.  If I try to change 'layout' in my code above to a FrameLayout and assign it as given in your answer, when I run my app I get *'The specified child already has a parent, you must call removeView() on the child's parent first'* - any ideas what this means exactly ?  I runs fine if I just create my layout as I've stated in my original question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Zippy the view's you're `add`ing must be parent-less, i.e. they have to be created programmatically.

Comment: user3249477, the 2 views I'm attempting to add are created programatically - one is a 'View' (splashscreen) and the other is a 'GLSurfaceView' (myGLView) - my code uses no XML at all, if that's what you mean?  It's all Java.  Also, by 'parentless' I assume this means that I've not added them to any other layouts already which I haven't.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding - thanks for your help

Comment: @Zippy try adding a simple RelativeLayout with a red background.

Comment: Hi @user3249477 - I kind of had some success with this, the strange thing is that it was **setContentView(layout);** that was causing this error - is it right that I don't need to call that?!  Seems odd.  But if I don't call it everything works OK and my view heirarchy looks similar to those other apps I mentioned in my original question - cheers.

Comment: @Zippy I wouldn't bother with that though. Xml makes things more clear as java code tends to get messy easily. An extra layout won't hurt you that much.

Comment: Well my relative layout was also created in Java!  Is it normal not to have to setContentView(); ?  The only reason I was doing this is because I was trying to resolve some issues I was having with my Splashscreen, however it hasn't really helped much.  I was just curous about the setContentView thing.

Comment: @Zippy from [Activity.java source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) you can see that `setContentView` doesn't do anything special (expect maybe inits ActionBar). It's fine not to use it as long as you add the layout yourself before calling something like `findViewById`.